# C# output in weird format

Tags: c#, encoding

It have been few weeks what I am trying to get output from CURL request.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://example/Login"))
        {
            request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "application/json");

            request.Content = new StringContent("{\"username\":\"username\",\"password\":\"password\"}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var task = httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            task.Wait();
            var response = task.Result;

            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

From this I am getting this output :

```
StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Tue, 09 Oct 2018 12:23:28 GMT
  Date: Tue, 09 Oct 2018 12:23:29 GMT
  Connection: close
  Set-Cookie: TS0119a36f=015d5689807756bd7792c622b0d146d50f8131b81e7cfa77d76c0b50114e2d09340d72b8f8ea0462c3476511b8474077967ae579e7; Path=/; Domain=.example.com
  Transfer-Encoding: chunked
  Content-Type: application/json
}
```

But when I execute CURL from cmd i get this (also what I need from c#)

> {"code":200,"status":"success","sessionId":"35aaf800-bfdb-11e8-991a-d35512019464"}

My guess is that I have bad encoding. But I cant figure out..

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(response);` is wrong, that's the entire response (headers, status code, etc). You want `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`

Comment: You getting response header and your json is in the body. Here are some [examples](https://johnthiriet.com/efficient-api-calls/)

Comment: You don't need to specify `Encoding.UTF8`, that's the default. `task.Result` blocks just like `task.Wait()`, which means you can remove `task.Wait()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos UTF8 is the default in some systems, not all. Also, you have to specify it in order to use the overload that allows you to specify `application/json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks boys, u are the best

```
Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

works for me